# Storing User's Game Progress

Tags: android, ios

I'm working on a cross platform game which will support both logins and 'guest' play. The benefit to logging in is, of course, that your game progress will be saved and accessible via multiple devices. For guest play I'll just be storing game progress locally via JSON or something similar.

What do you see as the best way of saving game progress externally? When the user logs in, their completion should be fetched and updated locally, and when the user completes an action (beats a level, etc.) their completion should be updated locally and then pushed to the external source, too.

Initially I was considering just MySQL with a Levels table or something similar, but would a JSON approach (MongosDB, maybe?) be best? What would you recommend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to spend time learning a web language and database, you can use a Backend as a Service (BaaS) provider like [Parse.com](http://parse.com)

If you do want to learn a web language and database, you can take your pick of anything, really. Your problem is simple and it'll make an effective learning exercise no matter what you choose.

Comment: When the user accesses the level map, I'd like to check level completion. Does having a table (with the user ID being the key) of levels with the completion percentage for each (and querying each) seem like an efficient means of doing it?

Comment: I think I would have a table of users, a table for levels, and a table that stores a user Id, level id, and completion percentage.

Answer (score 0):

**CoreData**. For both local and external use.

It has more than you asked for, but may be challenging to get into.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, also SQLite should do the job. I could say that is lighter than Core Data.

*SQLite is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world. The source code for SQLite is in the public domain.*

[SQLite](https://sqlite.org/)